# str not callable discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to build a bot which can submit and store attachments. Right now, I got this. But it says `'str' not callable`

```py
async def submit(message):
    attachment = Message.attachments
    if Message.attachments:
        with open('submit.txt', "a") as file:
            file.write(f"{str(message.author.id)(message)(attachment.url)}\n")
            if message == None:
                file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)(message)(attachment.url)}\n")
        if message.attachment == None:
            await message.channel.send("Please attach a file")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and checked out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? In particular, please include the full stack trace (not just the error message itself) and a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

In the `file.write` method call you must put your variables like this :

```
file.write(f"{message.id} - {message} - {attachment.url}")
```

Do not put more than one expression in braces.